# Los valores del vector no coinciden con los introducidos

Tags: c

Estoy en los primeros pasos de aprender a programar en `c` y no se porque me esta pasando lo siguiente, al momento de imprimir desde una función me da valores erróneos y no entiendo el por qué.

En la función `montosfacturas` que esta en el final del código y ejecuto a través de un `switch`. Ahí radica el principal problema. Corrí alguna prueba imprimiendo los valores de ambos vectores y en un primer momento me dan los valores indicados, pero cuando los imprimo en el `switch case 2` me encuentro con que ambos valores no concuerdan, aquí el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

void cantFacturas(int),montosFacturas(int fac[],int cVen[]);
float prmF = 0;
int factura = 1, contF = 0, menu = 20, art[] = {0}, i = 1, n = 1, f = 0, fac[] = {0}, codArt = 0, cantArt = 0, totalArt = 0, vArt = 0, Vfac = 0, CajaDiaria = 0, bandera = 0;
int valArt[] = {0}, valFac[] = {0}, cVen[ ]= {0}, mFV[][61] = {0}, Articulo[] = {0}, facturasArticulo[] = {0};

int main()
{
    system("cls");   

    while(menu != 9)
    {

        puts("\n...Elija su menu...\n");
        puts("Menu 0- Carga de Datos\n");
        puts("Menu 1- Cantidad de Facturas Emitidas\n");
        puts("Menu 2- Monto de Cada Factura\n");
        puts("Menu 3- Suma de las Facturas-Caja Diaria\n");
        puts("Menu 4- Cantidad Total de Articulos Vendidos\n");
        puts("Menu 5- Cantidad Vendida de cada Articulo\n");
        puts("Menu 6- Promedio de Importe de las Facturas\n");
        puts("Menu 7- Porcentual de cada Articulo sobre el Total\n");
        puts("Menu 8- Impresion Decendente del punto D\n");
        puts("Menu 9-Salir");
        puts("\nIngrese su Menu");
        scanf("%d", &menu);

        if(bandera == 0 && menu == 0)
        {
            switch(menu)    
            { 
                case 0:
                    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                    {
                        printf("Cargue el valor del Articulo Codigo =  %d\n",i);
                        scanf("%d", &vArt);
                        valArt[i] = vArt;
                        art[i] = i;
                    }

                    printf("\nIngrese el numero de Factura:   ");
                    scanf("%d", &fac[n]);
                    printf("el valor de fac[n] es %d", fac[n]);

                    while(fac[n] != 0)
                    {
                        printf("\nIngrese el codigo del Articulo:   ");
                        scanf("%d", &codArt);
                        printf("Ingrese la cantidad Vendida:   ");
                        scanf("%d", &cantArt);

                        cVen[n] = (cantArt * valArt[codArt]);//Punto B
                        CajaDiaria = CajaDiaria + (cantArt * valArt[codArt]);//Punto C
                        totalArt = totalArt + cantArt;//Punto D
                        Articulo[codArt] = (Articulo[codArt] + cantArt);//Punto E                             
                        facturasArticulo[codArt] = facturasArticulo[codArt]++;//punto F

                        n++;
                        contF++;//Punto A

                        printf("\nIngrese el numero de Factura:   ");
                        scanf("%d", &fac[n]);
                        printf("el valor de fac[n] es %d", fac[n]);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("\nNo es una opcion del menu. ");
                    break;
                }
                bandera=1;
            }
            else if(bandera == 1 && menu != 0)
            {
                switch(menu)
                {
                    case 1:
                        cantFacturas(contF);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        montosFacturas(fac,cVen);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                    case 9:
                        printf("Gracias por usar Pellerano Factura System!!!!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("\nNO EXISTE ESA OPCION");
                }
            }
            else if(menu != 0)
            {
                system("cls");
                printf("\nCargue los datos Primero");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nNo puede cargar mas datos");
            }
        }    
    return 0;
}

void cantFacturas(int)
{
    printf("\nLa cantidad de Facturas emitidas es: %d", contF);
}

void montosFacturas(int fac[], int cVen[])
{

    for(i = 1; i <= contF; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEl valor de la factura %d es igual a %d", fac[i], cVen[i]);// porque cuando lo imprimo no devuelve los valores indicados??
    }
}
```

Comment: Si el programa está en C... ¿Qué hace ahí `iostream`? Esa librería es **exclusiva de C++**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que los **usas arrays de tamaño 1**:

```
int valArt[]={0};
```

He cogido este como muestra pero me vale cualquier otro. En esa línea estás declarando un array, `valArt`, con espacio para un único elemento... y estos arrays no se van a redimensionar en el futuro, luego si tu escribes en posiciones diferentes a `valArt[0]` pisarás memoria de otras variables.

Aquí tienes dos posibles soluciones:

**Determinas un número máximo de elementos y creas el array con ese tamaño**

Es una opción un tanto rígida pero funciona bien siempre y cuando el número de elementos no sea desproporcionado:

```
#define MAX_ELEMENTOS 40

int valArt[MAX_ELEMENTOS] = {0};
```

**Usas memoria dinámica**

Esta opción te permita usar almacenar todos los elementos que necesites, ya que podrás alterar el tamaño del array en tiempo de ejecución:

```
// Array para 40 elementos
int * valArt = (int*)malloc(40 * sizeof(int));


// Aumentamos la reserva a 80
int* ptr = (int*)realloc(valArt, 80 * sizeof(int));
if( ptr == 0 )
{
  // Error al reservar la memoria
}
valArt = ptr;


// Liberamos la memoria reservada para el array
free(valArt);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, hoy lo pruebo y les digo como me fue. Muchas gracias otra vez por la pronta respuesta!!!!